# Use Jekyll to generate static pages locally

Tags: jekyll

After reading some documentation, I find Jekyll-based project will work on a Jekyll aware web server, what if I just need to generate static pages locally, is there a way to publish locally, I just need the generated blogs locally and will host it in a plain static web hosting.

- Can Jekyll generate static pages locally (for blog posts)?
- Can Jekyll generate post or blog folder that can be navigated through a navbar which is part of the blog list template?
- What should be the format of the blog list to be able to be Jekyll-friendly?

Comment: I use it to produce a local website, no posts. That website uses relative URLs only, and can simply be transferred one to one to my online website. But it behaves exactly the same locally, simply loading the files. Not even a server is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers are yes, yes and liquid/html. Just install Jekyll locally and look for the generated _site folder. It will exceed your expectations, for sure.